# Can anyone help me figure out what this circuit does?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I wanted to see if anyone might be able to help me understand this circuit board a bit better. I am trying to trace some issues I'm having with my car stereo and this board is the furthest I can trace an expected voltage that isn't there. I am not sure what this specific board does. I attached some pictures with more detail after trying to model the schematic as best I could in Eagle.

Thanks in advance for any help!
[image: Picture of the circuit diagram I made based on the board.]
[image: Detail of the bottom half of the main board]
[image: Detail of the top half of the main board]
[image: Detail of the bottom half of the smaller board]

Comment: This schematic is illogical. Paired C-E's with no emitter current ( or missing dots) and single NPN also with no emitter current and FETs with shorted Vgs.  Try explaining your real issues before and now.

Comment: The real issue is that I don't understand the circuit. I included the images of the hardware so anyone with more knowledge could help me make sense of it. So I think with the paired C-E's that you're talking about, that's the 2nd image in the post., with the C3518 transistors, I found the datasheet for that part, and I can pretty clearly see that the E pins on both are connected, as well as the C pins, so I'm not sure what to actually do about that, but I modeled the schematic as best I could.

Comment: Does the radio have a vacuum fluorescent display? This looks like it could be the voltage converter for one of those.

Comment: It does indeed, the main problem I have is that is am following the 65V from the VFD back and it has led me to this board. I think now its a matter of determining which components on this board have gone bad then.

Comment: The first thing that looks bad is the cracked PCB

Comment: Were there some bulged e-caps removed?

Comment: Yea the cracked PCB was my doing, but I do have a spare (that also doesn't work). Knowing it didn't work before the PCB cracked tells me it's probably some common failure component for these radios. I de-soldered the 3 largest caps and tested them with the multimeter and the resistance changed like I expected so I believe they aren't the problem. I haven't checked the last cap on the smaller PCB so that'll be next.

Alternatively, I'm thinking it might be smarter to try an off the shelf voltage converter I can wire in in the same spot.

Comment: Are these three different PCBs? I don’t follow. Bottom one looks like a replacement board for a vacuum tube.

Comment: @winny: The bottom picture is the underside of the white board shown in the middle picture.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yup that's correct, the 1st and 2nd picture are both sides of the same board, which I've tried to model as the upper half of the schematic, and the 3rd picture is the underside of the smaller PCB that sits on top of the main one.

Comment: The schematic may have errors and as shown is unrecognizable but , certainly some type of voltage regulators. So just repair the broken parts , find 0V and Vcc then use component specs like Vbe , Ic to see what has failed after all repairs..  Try fixing broken PWB with FR4 edge ribs + PU or epoxy or crazy glue

Comment: Oh! Is that drum core a transformer with really strange bobbin/pin arrangement?

Comment: @winny Good question, any idea how I might test that? It's got 8 pins, only 4 are actually connected to the copper windings. I figured it was some sort of inductor but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Multimeter set to beep/continuity testing and find out where each winding is.